# How to create a react web app for Android using webpack and manifest.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, webpack

My webapp uses react+webpack.

With "offline-plugin" its creates a service worker and manifest for static caching.

The final piece of the puzzle is creating a manifest.json enabling a splash screen on Android.

I have added as [instructed](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android) the following link to the manifest:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

But the manifest.json content has its links that webpack is not parsing so it doesn't work in production, what should do?

Json sample:

```
{
  "short_name": "Kinlan's Amaze App",
  "name": "Kinlan's Amazing Application ++",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",[enter link description here][2]
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-3x.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "landscape"
}
```